# MAUI-Blazor add AdditionalAssembly programmatically

Tags: maui-blazor, razor-class-library

I am trying to found a good way to arrange my Razor class libraries to let use them in MAUI Blazor hybrid applications

My problem is about the route when the class libraries contains componentes with `@page` directive.
I saw that if I have a MAUI Blazor application and I want to use a Razor class library (that contains pages) I have to add a reference to the library and add to in Main.razor at Router `AdditionalAssemblies` the asembly of Razor class library. I not like so much this, I am used that if I add a referece to a class library, all the library "resources" are availables, anyway is accettable.

My big problem is when my library use another library that also contains pages.
In this case I have to tell to my library user the list of assembly that my library uses and he have to add in the him Router component `AdditionalAssemblies` and more are the libraries my main library uses more long is the list of assebly I have to provide to my library users to let them add to their AdditionalAssemblies application Roter component.
This for me is very ugly so I am looking for a way to avoid this, for example I'd like tell to the library users "add this `UseMyLibrary()` in the service configuration(or somethig like this)" and this method will do all the work that the router component do for the `AdditionalAssemblies`.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Per [Share assets across native clients using a Razor class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-7.0), you can add the [AdditionalAssemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#route-to-components-from-multiple-assemblies) to specify the location of any [shared routable components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#route-templates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to do like that, aeach library exposes a class like this:

```
public static class RouteAdditionalAssemblies
{
    public static IEnumerable<Assembly> AdditionalAssemblies
    {
        get
        {
            return Enumerable.Repeat(typeof(RouteAdditionalAssemblies).Assembly, 1).Concat(Library2.RouteAdditionalAssemblies.AdditionalAssemblies);
        }
    }
}
```

So in the Main.razor at Router AdditionalAssemblies I can just Add

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Main).Assembly"
        AdditionalAssemblies="Library1.RouteAdditionalAssemblies.AdditionalAssemblies ">
```

So, if library1 will add some reference to another library that contains pages, I have to add it just on `Library1.RouteAdditionalAssemblies.AdditionalAssemblies` property

Comment: Good job! You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.