# dotnet maui blazor hybrid shared pages

Tags: blazor, maui

hello i start to build a app (web store) that needs to be for the web and the mobile

on the mobile i need to use basic product features

i pick dotnet blazor becuase its a multy platfrom shared code

i build 5 layers

- SharedClasses - dotnet standard
- SharedGui - razor class lib
- ApiServer - dotnet core api
- WebClient - blazor server app
- NativeApp - dotnet maui blazor app

i connect them and i get the shared pages/routes from the SharedGui in the WebClient app

but

not in the maui app

i try to find something on the add " AdditionalAssemblies " but i not found for maui only for blazor web server app

Comment: Does this help? [MAUI-Blazor add AdditionalAssembly programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76139992/maui-blazor-add-additionalassembly-programmatically)

Comment: Glad it helps! Feel free to share your solution if you resolved this issue. By the way, here I also found some info : [\[Bug\] MAUI Blazor - Router AppAssembly could not find pages if assembly is differen](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3258).